# Seamless move of an arrow in a loop with css animation

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a seamless loop of one arrow inside a div.

I am using two SVG arrows and what I am trying to archieve is when the top of the first arrow is partly hidden the same part of the second one should be shown so it seems like only one arrow is used and it is moving in the loop (when the first arrow reaches the top of the div and the 50% of it is hidden then the 50% of the second one should be shown at the bottom).

```css
.arrows-wrapper {
  width: 124px;
  height: 83px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.arrows-wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
}

.arrows {
  animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
}

.arrow2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -25px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, -125px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-wrapper">
  <svg width="124" height="197" viewBox="0 0 124 197">
    <g class="arrows arrow1">
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,110 61,104 72,110"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="none" points="50,116 61,110 72,116"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,122 61,116 72,122"></polyline>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <svg width="124" height="197" viewBox="0 0 124 197">
    <g class="arrows arrow2">
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,110 61,104 72,110"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="none" points="50,116 61,110 72,116"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,122 61,116 72,122"></polyline>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

See [the demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoxoMv) of what I have got so far (two arrows are visible at once but only one arrow or part of it should be visible at the same time).

The result I need:
[image: Result]

The question is if it's possible to archieve.

Comment: And the question is...? Try use SVG as background

Comment: The question is added. Example of "Try use SVG as background"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: Just needed to tweek the translate in your css animation.

```css
.arrows-wrapper {
  width: 124px;
  height: 83px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
}

.arrows-wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
}

.arrows {
  animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
}

.arrow2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -25px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, -200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows-wrapper">
  <svg width="124" height="197" viewBox="0 0 124 197">
    <g class="arrows arrow1">
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,110 61,104 72,110"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="none" points="50,116 61,110 72,116"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,122 61,116 72,122"></polyline>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <svg width="124" height="197" viewBox="0 0 124 197">
    <g class="arrows arrow2">
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,110 61,104 72,110"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4" fill="none" points="50,116 61,110 72,116"></polyline>
      <polyline stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="none" points="50,122 61,116 72,122"></polyline>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```